# Can't play local files in movieplayer in xamarin after iOS9 update

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Here is my code :

```
moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerViewController(NSUrl.FromFilename("examplevideo.mp4"));
this.PresentModalViewController(moviePlayer, true); 
moviePlayer.MoviePlayer.PrepareToPlay(); moviePlayer.MoviePlayer.Play();
```

This all done on button clicks.

Comment: Not sure about `xamarin` but did you try without extension `.mp4` ? and play before presenting.

Comment: after iOS9 or Xcode9??